# Search bar cannot find child products in my website

Tags: wordpress, woocommerce, variable-product

I am making a website with WordPress and the search bar cannot find child products in variation products. All the child products got their own unique SKU but still I don't know what to do in order to make it work.

[This is the setup of the parent](https://i.stack.imgur.com/pxRfY.png)

[This is the setup of the child products](https://i.stack.imgur.com/iTybL.png)

[And this is the result that I get](https://i.stack.imgur.com/TiQRw.png)